# Only allow creation of has_many in ActiveAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

I have a `has_many` relation for which I have disabled destroying:

```
unless f.object.new_record?
  f.inputs do
    f.has_many :foos, allow_destroy: false do |foo|
      foo.input :bar
    end
  end
end
```

Currently once I've saved the main object and go back and edit, I can edit previously created `foo`s. I'd like this to not be the case and only have the ability to add new ones. How can I achieve this?

I can see ActiveAdmin provides `allow_destroy` and `new_record`, but there isn't something analogous to `allow_edit`.

Comment: Mhhhh I must admit, I believe activeadmin doesn't have native support for what you are asking (no confirmation though), but I digged a lot in it and didn't find any way to set the record as `readonly` in any place. May I suggest you a naive solution where you output html instead of form fields directly in the form definition? Possibly with a helper or such a thing

Comment: @Fire-Dragon-DoL Figured it out :) Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Great. Yeah you ended up with an idea similar to mine, looks like there isn't a built-in way

Answer (score 2):

Turns out the answer was staring me in the face: `new_record?`. Simply check whether the `has_many` item is a new record or not:

```
f.inputs do
  f.has_many :foos, allow_destroy: false do |foo|
    if foo.object.new_record?
      foo.input :bar
    end
  end
end
```